# Iterator VS HashMap<String, Object> in JAVA

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

Lets say that we have a collection of items. Which of the two is faster?

```
HashMap<String, ObjectFoo> hashmap = new HashMap<String, ObjectFoo>();
/* .... add elements .... */
ObjectFoo theElement = hashmap.get("nameOfObject");
```

Or

```
ArrayList<ObjectFoo> arraylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
/* .... add elements .... */
Iterator<ObjectFoo> itFoo = arraylist.iterator();
ObjectFoo obj;
while(itFoo.hasNext()) {
  obj = itFoo.next();
  if (obj.name.equals("nameOfObject")) return obj;
}
```

Suppose that:

```
public class ObjectFoo {
  public String name;
}
```

Comment: The only reason hashtables exist is the speed of random access. So take a guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `HashMap` is (alsmost always) faster. If you know [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) 
then using `HashMap` is O(1) while using (unsorted) `ArrayList` is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

HashMap stores key-value paris in buckets based on hashcode of key. Buckets are organized with array and accessing array is `O(1)`.

So when you call `hashmap.get("nameOfObject");` it calculates hashcode of key and then picks bucket with elements containing pairs where key has same hashcode as hascode of key used as argument.

Sometimes there will be more few key-value pairs which key has same hashcode. In that cases map will need to iterate over them and check if our key is equal to key in that pair, but since number of elements with same hashcode is very small iterating over them is way faster than iterating over all elements stored in map.